# Error in SpQuery Datetime comparison using javascript

Tags: javascript, spquery

I am trying to  take the count of records in a list within a date period.
my query render like this

```
  var qry = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Requested_x0020_Date' /><Value  Type='DateTime'>" + weekDates["start"].toString() +
                "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Requested_x0020_Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + weekDates["end"].toString() +
                "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";

 weekDates["start"]="dd/MM/yyyy" .

my function is 
 $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "Service Requests",
                CAMLQuery: qry,
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
                completefunc: weeklyCount
            });
```

It gives zero count and an error in console 
`http://devappsrv2/EN/HelpDesk/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` 500 (Internal Server Error)

Please help me.
thanks

Comment: <Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Requested_x0020_Date' /><Value  Type='DateTime'>" + weekDates["start"].toString() +
                "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Requested_x0020_Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + weekDates["end"].toString() +
                "</Value></Leq></And></Where>

Answer (score 0):

Check you are using SharePoint datetime format `"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ"` for querying date(`weekDates` variable).
Also add `IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'` with value type in the caml query.

```
var qry = "<Where>"+
        "<And>"+
            "<Geq><FieldRef Name='Requested_x0020_Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + weekDates["start"].toString() +"</Value></Geq>"+
            "<Leq><FieldRef Name='Requested_x0020_Date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + weekDates["end"].toString() +"</Value></Leq>"+
        "</And>"+
    "</Where>";
```